# Adding ads to an Android camera app

Tags: android, admob

I'm new to Android, and I've just finish a very simple camera Android app.

I'm looking for a solution for an ad (advertising baner or something like this) in my camera app. I want the ad to be displayed when I open my app and for the user to be able to take a picture even when the ad's displaying.

I think I can create an ad banner in a dialog, should I do that?

Comment: Have you read the AdMob quick start (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start)?  It can help you get started with a simple banner ad in a sample project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do AdMob. The ad appears at the bottom side of the camera.

```
// Find your main layout and add a new AdView to it:
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1);        
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "abcdefgh");
mainLayout.addView(adView,rlParams);
// Load the ad:     
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Oh. It worked. Thanks a lots . But if i'm using linear layout,i don't want to change to relative layout . How can i revise your codes ?

Comment: Just change the `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` in the code. Also remove the `.addRule()` method.

Comment: How can i put the banner into the corner ?

Comment: oh. i can do it now. But one more question : i want my app don't show the ad banner in the first time, just show the ad when the user open it on 2nd and 4th, 6th , 8th...How can i do ? and how can ad automaticly be closed ?

Comment: @KyDoan you can do this with SharedPreferences, each time the app is started, increment an integer in SharedPreferences, and on start, check if it is even, and show / hide the ad appropriately.